# Get Whether the user is scrolling a DataGridView or not

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking to find out whether the user is currently holding down the vertical scroll bar or not.

This question spawns from the fact that scrolling is cancelled when a DataGridView's DataSource is updated.

What I'm hoping for is to make an extension method like `IsUserScrolling()` to put on the `DataGridView`. The idea is that I don't update the DataGridView until the user stops scrolling.

Comment: Mr Universe, if my answer helped you please accept it, if you have any further question i'm here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've searched it and found an answer. it might not be the perfect answer, but it works:

i've created a `dataGridView`, and Created an `hScrollBar`, put the `hScrollBar` on top of the `dataGridView` scroll bar (you can use `vScrollBar` if you meant vertical), set the width of the scroll bar to be the same as the `dataGridView`, and on the Scroll event, i did:

```
  private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
  {
     dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = hScrollBar1.Value;
  }
```

and this way you can use the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events of the `hScrollBar`. you well come

Answer (score 2):

You can know if user scroll the `DataGridView` via `Scroll` event, you can know if user holding mouse down on the `Thumb` and scroll via its `ScrollEventArgs` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){
  if(e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll &&
     (e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement || e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement)){
     //your code here
  }
}
```

The code above almost works well, however somehow you can change the `VerticalScroll.Value` (this doesn't exist) with `Large Change` programmatically, the event will be fired even when user doesn't hold mouse down on vertical thumb. So we can add condition `MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left` to make it work better:

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){
  if(e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll && MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left &&
     (e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement || e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement)){
     //your code here
  }
}
```

Another short way to detect if user holding mouse down everywhere on the vertical scrollbar (both `Thumb` and `Arrow Repeat button`) using `HitTest` method, you can add more code to make it work more reliably so that we don't miss some kind of programmatical scroll with real user scrolling action:

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e){
  Point p = dataGridView1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
  if (dataGridView1.HitTest(p.X, p.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.VerticalScrollBar){
     //Your code here
  }
}
```